how to store user input inside loop in a variable?
int main()
{
    int greatest = 45;
    int num ;

    while(num > 0 )
    {
        printf("enter number-");
        scanf("%d" , &num);
        if (num > greatest)
            greatest = num ;
        else
            continue;
    }
}

Where did the problem occurred ?
So, when I try to run the program I got the message "enter number". but when I try to break the loop by entering 0 I get only blank space.
Title justification
Maybe I am wrong, but I feel that I declare the variable to store only a single input. So that's why I am facing a problem. So I tried to rectify this problem by declaring that variable as an array. But when i try to run program , I get never ending "Enter Number" messages
Also I am new to programming . so please don't give negative vote to my post since i have to wait for 5 days.

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

"but when I try to break the loop by entering 0 I get only blank space." what do you mean by this? Does your code exit the loop?

continue does the opposite of what I think you mean by "break"; continue jumps back to the beginning of the loop, it appears you want program flow to jump to the statement after the loop.

Note that uninitialized local variables, like num, will have an indeterminate value. It's usually best to look at it as garbage.

Should there perhaps be another printf at the end, displaying the result?

"So I tried to rectify this problem by declaring that variable as an array.": there is no array in your code.

The idiomatic way would be something like this:
#include <stdio.h>   // you forgot this in your code

int main(void)
{
  int greatest = 0;  // initial greatest value is 0 (assuming
                     // we deal only with positive numbers)

  while (1)          // loop forever
  {
    printf("Enter number: ");
    int num;         // declare num locally, but it's actually not
                     // a problem to declare it outside the while loop
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num == 0)
      break;          // if number entered is 0 we stop the loop

    if (num > greatest)
      greatest = num;
  } 

  printf("greatest = %d\n", greatest);  // we need to print the result
}

Problems in your original code:
int main()
{
    int greatest = 45;  // why 45 ? This is pointless, should be 0
    int num ;  // here num is declared but not initialized, 
               // it contains an undetermined value

    while(num > 0 )  // you're using num when its content is undetermined
    {
        printf("enter number-");
        scanf("%d" , &num);
        if (num > greatest)
            greatest = num ;
        else
            continue;    // the else continue is pointless
    }                    // you could as well drop it
}


Thank you for this detailed explanation. But i have some doubt :- Is it because i declare num outside the loop is the main problem of my program?

@arnold declaring num inside or outside the loop doesn't matter. It's mainly a question of style. Nowadays variables should be declared in the scope where they are used. The actual problem regarding num is that you use it in the condition in while when it contains an undetermined value. But as mentioned in the comments I put into your original code, there are more than one problems.

Ok  , but when i try to run this program i get message "enter number" so why i get this ? meaning since at first 'num' has no value so how 'while' got executed?

@arnold while (1) basically means the loop runs forever until you stop it with the break statement. This is basic C knowledge and it's certainly mentioned somewhere in your C text book. Are the comments in my code not clear enough?

No, it's more than enough. Thank you so much.

First initialize num to any number greater than zero (num=1) so that your while loop can start iterating.
Then after the braces of the while loop add a printf(num);

The first advice is okay. The second will not work. And it's not the only problem.

In this snippet he probably want the print function to print the value of greatest.

There are many errors in OP code, your answer is only about one of them.

you can use another type of loop too
int main(void)
{
    int greatest = -1;
    int num ;

    do
    {
        printf("\nenter number-");
        if(scanf("%d" , &num) != 1) { /* handle io error*/}
        if (num > greatest)
            greatest = num ;
    }while(num >= 0 );
    if(greatest < 0)
        printf("No valid numbers were entered\n");
    else
        printf("Greatest number : %d\n", greatest);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/sW9oox6PK

DV???? Elaborate

Apparently, OP wanted 0 as break value, not negative value...

@Bruno rather easy to change

@0_ still... The OP is really  a beginner, I think it would be better to amend your answer. I can do the change if you wish. Note that the downvote is not from me: your answer is fine.
